# How to make certain widgets not to show up on a mobile version of a site

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, widget

I have recently placed google ads on my [website](http://nix-pix.co.uk), and the site is mobile optimized, but the ads are too big for a phone and I do not want them to show up. I am running my site on Wordpress and I put the ads using widgets, so can you please tell me if there is any kind of plugin that disables certain widgets for a mobile phone?

Thanks!

**Edit:** One of the answers below said that I could use mdetect.php. How can I implement this into Wordpress? Please help! (sorry for my bad php!)

Answer (score 0):

Check out mdetect.php  http://code.google.com/p/mobileesp/source/browse/PHP/mdetect.php

It's really simple to use:

- create the uagent object
- add an if ($uagent->TypeOfPhone) and you can precesely control what is shown to which devices (so you can target tablets and not phones, for example)

There are other methods based on screen resolutions, but that's now getting tricky with "retina displays" that have more pixels than you can see. So I use mdetect now. Very reliable so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide this portion by adding "display:none" css code in media query for mobile.